# EC2 Flask API Request Timeout if python dependencies are imported

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, flask-restful

I am building a Flask API on EC2 which does a machine learning forward pass on POSTed text data.

My ec2 instance has all dependencies installed and any simple Flask application works perfectly when I run it in a browser.  However, the same simple applications (“Hello world” demos) do not work when I include the ML python library imports needed for my final application at the top of my app.py file.

Further details:

- There are no errors in the error log, but the server doesn’t load for
  any requests. API calls just perpetually wait for a response and the
  request usually times out.
- The ec2 setup I'm using is based on this tutorial:
  https://vishnut.me/blog/ec2-flask-apache-setup.html This link should
  contain the wsgi format I'm using & the only way I differ is by
  running in Python 3.6 on a Ubuntu 18.02 instance.
- I’ve upgraded the EC2 instance to a c4.large, but this hasn’t helped.

All my Flask app’s imports that cause the API
not to load are copied below.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, marshal
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import scipy
import requests
import numpy as np
import json
```

requirements.txt

```
00aniso8601==8.0.0
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
future==0.18.2
idna==2.9
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib==0.15.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
nltk==3.5
numpy==1.19.0
packaging==20.4
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytz==2020.1
regex==2020.6.8
requests==2.24.0
sacremoses==0.0.43
scikit-learn==0.23.1
scipy==1.5.0
torch==1.5.1
transformers==2.11.0
sentence-transformers==0.2.6.1
sentencepiece==0.1.91
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
tokenizers==0.7.0
tqdm==4.46.1
urllib3==1.25.9
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

sample "Hello World" app

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, marshal
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import scipy
import requests
import numpy as np
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Does the error only occur on EC2? What happens if you run it locally with debug=True?

Comment: Only occurs on EC2, it works excellent when I run it locally!

Comment: Can you provide your `requirements.txt` file as well as full hello world code. I can try to replicate the issue.

Comment: Updated the main question!

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? @GeoS

Comment: Ended up using a docker container! @hkjhadj1